# swift2.0 プロトコルを適合した要素のArrayの扱いに関して

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

下記のようにプロトコルを適合した要素の配列に関する質問です。

下記のようなケースで配列のcontainsが使用できなくなるのですがこういった場合に
配列に任意のobjectが含まれているかどうか判定する際の適切な方法が知りたいです。

正確には、contains(predicate: (XXX) throws -> Bool)しか利用できずcontains(element: XXX)のファンクションが利用できなくなっています。
indexOf関数でも同様のことが発生していました、

もちろん、

```
private var array = [String]()
```

などで試した場合は問題ありませんでした。

```
protocol ProtocolA : class {
    func someFunc()
}

class ClassA {
    private var array = [ProtocolA]()

    func testFunc(object: ProtocolA) {
        array.contains(object) // エラーになる
    }
}
```

Comment: `contains()`、`indexOf()`を使えるようにするには、`ProtocolA`が、プロトコル`Equatable`を継承している必要があります。プロトコル`Equatable`を調べれば、納得のいく結論が得られると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
試みてみます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains(element: XXX)`はSequenceTypeのextensionとして、次のように定義されています。

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Return `true` iff `element` is in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}
```

この定義、要素型である`Generator.Element`は、`Equatable`プロトコルに「適合」している必要があります。(「継承」ではありません。)残念ながら現在のSwiftのプロトコルの仕様では、`Equatable`を継承したプロトコルは定義できても、`Equatable`に適合するプロトコルは定義できないようです。(やり方をご存知の方がおられましたら、お知らせください。)

あなたが見つけられたもう一つの`contains(predicate: (XXX) throws -> Bool)`は以下のように定義されており、要素型に特定の条件はありません。

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Return `true` iff an element in `self` satisfies `predicate`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
}
```

プロトコルを`:class`として定義してあれば、`===`演算子が使えますので、こちらの方の`contains`を使った方が確実なのではないかと思います。

```
class ClassA {
    private var array = [ProtocolA]()

    func testFunc(object: ProtocolA) {
        array.contains{$0 === object}
    }
}
```

お試しください。